# Image not cropped only for browsers?

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, gd

I cropped an image using PHP GD `imagecopyresampled()` function.
I used the function in the past, but now it seems that somehow, for browsers like Firefox & Chrome (latest versions of both) the image is not really cropped, but somehow transparent in the part that should be removed.

[image]

The OSX finder and Photoshop shows correct image sizes and no transparency...

What could be wrong?

This is the code for jpg images...

```
        if(!($sourceImage = @imagecreatefromjpeg($source)))
        {
            $image = imagecreate($width, $height);
            $colorWhite = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
            $colorBlack = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
            imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colorWhite);
            imagestring($image, 1, 1, 10, "Immagine non disponibile", $colorBlack);
            imagejpeg($image, $destination);
            return(FALSE);
        }

        $destinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

        imagecopyresampled($destinationImage, $sourceImage,0,0,$x,$y,$width,$height,$width,$height);
        imagejpeg($destinationImage, $destination);
```

[image]

Comment: Is it being loaded from cache? Post the PHP code that you use to crop it.

Comment: Added :) No caching AFAIK. Clearing the cache in both browsers didn't work.

Comment: Plus, why JPGs have transparency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to VirtualBox & Apache behaviour on guests OS.

I solved with [this](http://codeblow.com/questions/shared-folder-in-virtualbox-for-apache/) change into the Apache2 Configuration.